# Facebook login re-authentication

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, spotify

When using Spotify, the users can do the following.

1. Login using Facebook on a device
2. Go off to another device and put their Facebook email & password and Spotify let's them log in!

How do they do the second step? I've looked over the Facebook developers documentation and can't find where to do it, I also can't see it in many other apps.

Any ideas how Spotify can use a Facebook email/password pair to log in with Spotify on subsequent logins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a password when you want to login via username:password on a device whilst initially setting your account up with FB login.
If you had your account set up with username:password you can still login via facebook. This is done by mapping the e-mails (+ checking if they are verified for the facebook account)